# Name of similar elements of symmetric group

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

For permutations of length $n$ of the symmetric group $S_n$, they can be arranged as follows (for example, $S_4$):

```
(1234) (2341) (3412) (4123)
(1243) (2431) (3124) (4312)
(1324) (2413) (3241) (4132)
(1342) (2134) (3421) (4213)
(1423) (2314) (3142) (4231)
(1432) (2143) (3214) (4321)
```

Is there a name for the rows? For the columns?

Comment: If what you wrote are meant to be [cycles][1], then every row represents thevery same cycle (permutation)...[1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is cycle notation and you mean *cycles* of length $n$:

Each row is simply four way of writing down *the same permutation*.

I'm not aware of any nice name for the columns; they would usually be considered unimportant groupings based on accidents of your *notation* for permutations.

Answer (score 1):

If these are the permutations of $S_4$, denoted using the second row of [two-line notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Notation), then we have:

- The column $j$ contains the permutations $\sigma \in S_4$ for which $\sigma(1)=j$.
- The rows list the permutations $\sigma \in S_4$ composed with powers of the $4$-cycle $(1234)$ [in [cycle notation]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation).  That is $$\sigma,\sigma \circ (1234),\sigma \circ (1234)^2,\sigma \circ (1234)^3.$$

Comment: I agree with your comment on the columns. However, your comment on the rows is incorrect. As Henning pointed out in his answer, the rows each contain a single element of $S_{4}$, just written in 4 different ways.

Comment: @DavidWard: Not under Rebecca's assumption that what we're seeing is the second rows of two-line notation. (Which is arguably just as reasonable an assumption than that they're cycles).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry my mistake. I had missed that part of Rebecca's answer!

Comment: By the way, with this assumption each row is a _left coset_ of the subgroup generated by (2 3 4 1).